# Using "expect" without a matching function (with Supertest and Jest)

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I recently ran into the following testing code in an Express app using [Supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) and [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started):

```
const supertest = require("supertest");
const app = require("../app");
const api = supertest(app);

test("notes are returned as json", async () => {
  await api
    .get("/api/notes")
    .expect(200)
    .expect("Content-Type", /application\/json/);
});
```

I'm kind of confused where the `.expect(200)` is coming from. Is this part of Supertest? Because I know that in Jest when we call `expect` we typically use a matcher like this:

```
expect(200).toBe(200)
```

But somehow this test works without having to call a matcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Supertest v6.3.1*

[`.expect()`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/v6.3.1/lib/test.js#L71) API comes from the `Test` class of the `supertest` package. The key code for handling `.expect(200)`:

```
// status
if (typeof a === 'number') {
  this._asserts.push(wrapAssertFn(this._assertStatus.bind(this, a)));
  // body 
  // ...
}
```

The status code will be used like this:

```js
wrapAssertFn(this._assertStatus.bind(this, 200))
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/v6.3.1/lib/test.js#L81)

The [`this._asserts`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/v6.3.1/lib/test.js#L31) array holds all the assertion. Supertest will check each assertion until finding a failed assertion [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/v6.3.1/lib/test.js#L164)